# Reading XML JS - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The only way I can read the XML at the moment is to add functions to the "parse" function but I want to be able to add functions outside that function. When I click the Match button nothing happens. Although the function inside the parse function works. I see most people use "XML" instead of "document" but when I add xml instead of document I get the error "ReferenceError: xml is not defined".

I would like to run functions on the xml outside the parse function. Thanks for your help.

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function(){alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");}
 });
 });

 function parse(document){
 $(document).find('Swatch').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('name'));
 });
 }

 $('#Match').on('click', function () {
 $(document).find('Swatch').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('name'));
 });
 });
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fabric>
        <Swatch name="2016" title="Ruby_Red" alt="Main" match="2004, 2005, 2020, 2026, 2035"></Swatch>
        <Swatch name="2004" title="Spring_Yellow" alt="Knits"></Swatch>
        <Swatch name="2005" title="Newport_Navy" alt="Knits"></Swatch>
        <Swatch name="2006" title="Light_Purple" alt="Knits"></Swatch>
        <Swatch name="2007" title="Royal_Blue" alt="Knits"></Swatch>
        <Swatch name="2008" title="Ruby_Red" alt="Knits"></Swatch>              
</Fabric>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `document` in the `click` handler refers to the `window.document` object.

The `document` parameter in `parse` method is local to that method and will not exists after that method call is exited.

The solution here is to create a global variable which will hold the xml reference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function(){
            alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");
            xmldoc = undefined;
        }
    });
});

var xmldoc;
function parse(document){
    xmldoc = document;
    $(document).find('Swatch').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
}

$('#Match').on('click', function () {
    $(xmldoc).find('Swatch').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be forget to pass **document** to your function

Try this

```
$('#Match').click(function(document){
$(document).find('Swatch').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('name'));
 });
});
```